# Xamarin.formのWebViewについて

Tags: webview, xaml, xamarin

Xamarin.formのWebViewで困っております。
xamlにwebviewタグを実装し、例としてAmazonのページを表示しようとしております。

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="SampleClass.Amazon"
  xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:SampleClass;assembly=SampleClass"
  Title="{i18n:Translate Amazon}">
 
 <AbsoluteLayout>
  <WebView Source="{ StaticResource AmazonURL }"
   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
 </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

またコード内の「AmazonURL」は「App.xaml」に定義しております。

```html
<x:String x:Key="AmazonURL">http://amzn.to/1UKGpN9</x:String>
```

これで実機及びシミュレータ(iOS)で動作確認すると以下のように表示されません。

[image: AmazonのWebページ表示せず]

Safariで表示すると以下のページになります。

[image: Safari表示]

確認したところ、短縮URLでは表示されず、通常のURLなら表示します。
通常URLでは文字列が長くなりますので、短縮URLで表示するには
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
ご教授のほどお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

「App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP」というエラーが発生していると思います。

これでGoogle検索すると原因などがわかると思います。

- [[iOS 9] iOS 9 で追加された App Transport Security の概要 ｜ Developers.IO](http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/iphone/ios-9-intro-ats/)

こちらの「Info.plist の設定例」の「基本的にATS を有効にし、ATS の対象にしないドメインを Info.plist に記載する」参考に、`XXX.iOS` プロジェクトにある `Info.plist` ファイルに以下のように追記します(テキストエディタで編集した方がやりやすい、と個人的には思います)。

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>amzn.to</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

これで `amzn.to` の接続が許可され、 WebView で表示できるようになると思います。

Comment: developer.xamarin.comにも説明がありましたので追記します。

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/